# Convert Ai file to png without distorting the text

Tags: png, adobe-illustrator, cc

I created an image using Illustrator CC which I am converting into png and placing in an Indesign CC file to then export as pdf. I do 'Save for Web' in Illustrator to convert my ai file to .png. After conversion the text is badly distorted. I changed the font but its still the same. To try out I also placed the ai file in indd and that is distorted too. Can I get some help as to how to convert my file with text intact.

Comment: Off-topic for Stack Overflow (see the [help/on-topic]) but I've got to ask: why do you think it's necessary to save your Illustrator file as PNG before placing it into InDesign?

Comment: What's the distortion?